# Differences between two groups in molecular genetic

Tags: r, statistics

Usually I have some variable in 3 conditions in 2 groups. How can I find, is there are any statistic differences between this two groups?

For example short csv:

```
genotype,group,gene
5g/5g,1,PAI
5g/5g,1,PAI
4g/5g,1,PAI
4g/5g,1,PAI
4g/5g,1,PAI
4g/5g,1,PAI
5g/5g,1,PAI
4g/4g,1,PAI
4g/4g,1,PAI
4g/4g,2,PAI
4g/5g,2,PAI
4g/4g,2,PAI
4g/4g,2,PAI
4g/4g,2,PAI
4g/5g,2,PAI
5g/5g,2,PAI
4g/4g,2,PAI
5g/5g,2,PAI
5g/5g,2,PAI
5g/5g,2,PAI
4g/5g,2,PAI
```

gene PAI have 3 genotypes: 5g/5g, 4g/5g and 4g/4g.

If present this data in table format:

[image]

So, how can I find one p-value [like there](http://gen-exp.ru/calculator_or.php) - picture below? 
[image: picture below]

Comment: to clarify, a difference in what?  Proportions of each genotype between the two groups?

Comment: Yes, I think. As I can see (last pictire) to analyse differences whas used Chi-square test. And p-value=0,56. So, two groups have no any statistical differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this be what you're looking for?

```
## simulating some data
df <- data.frame(genotype=sample(c("5g/5g","4g/5g","4g/4g"),16,replace=T), group=c(rep(1,8), rep(2,8)))

df
##    genotype group
## 1     4g/5g     1
## 2     4g/5g     1
## 3     4g/5g     1
## 4     5g/5g     1
## 5     5g/5g     1
## 6     4g/4g     1
## 7     4g/4g     1
## 8     4g/5g     1
## 9     4g/4g     2
## 10    4g/4g     2
## 11    4g/4g     2
## 12    4g/5g     2
## 13    5g/5g     2
## 14    5g/5g     2
## 15    4g/5g     2
## 16    4g/4g     2

## first a table
with(df, table(group, genotype))
##      genotype
## group 4g/4g 4g/5g 5g/5g
##     1     2     4     2
##     2     4     2     2

## and maybe a chi-squared test is what you want?
with(df, chisq.test(table(group,genotype)))
##    Pearson's Chi-squared test

## data:  table(group, genotype)
## X-squared = 1.3333, df = 2, p-value = 0.5134
```

Note that this isn't with your real data, but you could do the same thing.

Comment: grate! but every time i have a warning "chisq.test(table(group, genotype)) :  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect". Is it becaue in test dataset some values are very small? So, if some values very small (sometimes I realy have 0 or 1 for some values) I need to use not chi-square test? I need to use fisher.test?

Comment: Good point.  The chi-squared approximation is less reliable with small sample sizes - you can generate a table of expected counts with `with(df, chisq.test(table(group,genotype)))$expected` - generally, if any expected counts are less than 5, the chi-squared test isn't recommended.  Alternatives are Fisher's exact test (which you found already!) or a chi-squared-ish test based on randomization, `with(df, chisq.test(table(group,genotype), simulate.p.value=T))`.  Maybe try both, and see if the p-values are similar?